# Django Material navbar issue

Tags: css, django, django-admin, materialize

We're using Django Material (MaterializeCSS as CSS framework) on a new project we are building, and we got an issue with a language selector in the admin navbar. The issue is happening on Firefox, not on Chrome, and I couldn't find what's causing this. Can you check it please? The URL is: https://accountant.swapps.io.

Here is how it looks for reference.

[image: navbar issue]

The templates doesn't have a lot, and the CSS for this is minimal but I can provide code if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown is set as a block element making it to take more space. This should fix it.

```
.nav-wrapper .select-wrapper input.select-dropdown {
    display: inline;
}
```